# How can I discover the GCP project my Cloud Run service is in?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a Java service running in Cloud Run. I have prod and stage GCP projects, and I want to be able to query other resources from the correct project at runtime, but having to add an environment variable to every service to configuration to tell it what project it is already in seems weird.

I have a similar question for finding out what IAM user the service is running as (for authentication with the DB in the same project)

I've been searching the GCP libraries (https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference) for this, but I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Run has the metadata service. You can issue HTTP GET requests to retrieve information.

The URL to request the project ID:

```
http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/
```

Include the HTTP Header `Metadata-Flavor:Google`.

For more information, see this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview). Each Google Cloud compute service includes the metadata service.